# Delphi : Unix Timestamp conversion

Tags: delphi

I am using the ZK software machine to set Daylight saving time and standard time. In the machine I have set the daylight saving time to 01.01 00:00 (DD.MM HH:MM) and the standard saving time to 31.12 23:59. When I retrieve the information from the machine the format for the time is in Int64 :

```
01.01 00:00 represents '16842752'  
31.12 23:59 represents '203364155'
```

I am not able to convert back the date to unix timestamp, I am not getting the same int64 value.

```
function TMachine.SetDayLightMode(): Boolean;
var
    BeginTime, EndTime : WideString;
    abegin, aend : TDateTime;
begin
    Result := false;
    with MachineDayLight do
    begin
        FCZKEM.GetSysOption(MachineNo, 'DaylightSavingTime', BeginTime); {16842752}
        CZKEM.GetSysOption(MachineNo, 'StandardTime', EndTime); {203364155}

        abegin := StrToDateTime('01.01.1970 00:00:00');
        AEND   := StrToDateTime('31.12.1970 23:59:00');


        BeginTime := IntToStr(DateTimeToUnix(TTimeZone.Local.ToUniversalTime(abegin,false))); //-14400 represents 25.25 19:19
        EndTime   := IntToStr(DateTimeToUnix(TTimeZone.Local.ToUniversalTime(AEND,false))); //31521540 represents 01.22 25:04


        FCZKEM.setSysOption(MachineNo, 'DaylightSavingTime', BeginTime);
        FCZKEM.setSysOption(MachineNo, 'StandardTime', EndTime);


    end;
end;
```

[EDITED]

Yes as per your comments I noticed it's not the unix timestamp that ZK is using. The documentation online doesn't state what time format the machine returns. The machine returns the following:

```
  1 min difference has a difference of 1 in its value 
  01.01 00:00 - 16842752 
  01.01 00:01 - 16842753

  1 hour difference gives a difference of 256 
  01.01 00:00 - 16842752 
  01:01 01:00 - 16843008

  1 day difference gives a difference of 65536
  01.01 01:00 - 16843008 
  02.01 01:00 - 16908544 

  1 month difference (31 days) returns 16777216
  01.01. 01:00 - 16843008
  01.02. 01:00 - 33620224

  01.03 01:00  - 50397440
  01.04 01:00  - 67174656
```

I'm not able to find out what representation of int64 the machine returns .

Comment: Your expected values are wrong. The Unix representation of 01/01/1970 00:00 is `0` (it's the base date), so it can't possibly represent `16842752`, and the representation for 12/31/1970 is `31535940`. I don't know what ZK is using for its time system, but it's not Unix time (or you've just made a mistake with your representations). You can confirm this yourself with `WriteLn(DateTimeToUnix(EncodeDateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)));`

Comment: What does the vendor say?

Comment: Display those integers as hex and you should see a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks,I got the solution the date was actually in hex format as pointed out by Rob Kennedy:

```
function TMachine.ConvertDateToMachineFormat: WideString;
var
    aMonth, aDay, aHour, aMin,aHexDate : String;
    aIntDate : Int64;
begin
   // 31.12 23:59 - 203364155
    aMonth := IntToHex(12,2);
    aDay   := IntToHex(31,2);
    aHour  := IntToHex(23,2);
    aMin   := IntToHex(59,2);

    aHexDate := aMonth + aDay + aHour + aMin;
    if (aHexDate <> '') and (aHexDate[1] <> '$') then
        aIntDate := StrToInt64Def('$' + aHexDate, 0)
    else
        aIntDate := StrToInt64Def(aHexDate, 0);

    Result := IntToStr(aIntDate);
end;
```

Comment: I don't really understand this question any more. I thought you were asking about Unix time conversion to date time. Now you are talking about the format used by some third party library that can't even be found by simple web search. One wonders why you didn't ask the vendor of that library, or read their documentation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : Thank you for your suggestion. At the beginning, I thought I was wrongly converting the date to unix but then with your suggestions I saw the machine date wasn't in unix format. I had a documentation that didn't give much detail of the daylight saving time and its format and I don't have direct contact with the vendor either. To contact the vendor  I need to escalate the issue to the upper hierarchy which would have taken a few days. I preferred to found out a solution first before moving to this step.